# Почему не работает верно анимация плагина wow при split тестах?

Tags: php, css, анимация, css-animation, split

При split- тестировании анимации сессии "wow", "not_wow" записываются в бд. Но эффекты работают и при параметре no_wow

Ошибки не выводятся, хотя в start.php подключено

```html
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    session_start();
```

Также в index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Переменные сессии вывожу так

```
print_r ($_SESSION);
Array ( [split] => no_wow )
```

/*или wow*/

Через var_dump

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

array(1) { ["split"]=> string(6) "no_wow" }
/*или wow*/

Код блока

```html
<div class="wrapp-help">
           
<!--1. подкл. 2 файла wow.min.js animate.css, 2 добавляем class wow и 2 парам. опр. дейст. 3 init в functions.js п.6: var wow = new WOW();
  wow.init();  -->
            <div class="help-content wow bounceInLeft" data-wow-duration="0.5s" data-wow-delay="0">
              <div class="h-image">
                <img src="/catalog/view/theme/default/image/icon1.png" alt="alt">
              </div>
              <div class="h-text">
                <h3>Текст</h3>
                <p>Текст</p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

В index.php вверху прописываю:

```html
<?php
  require_once "lib/start.php";
  unset ($_SESSION["camp_id"]);
  unset ($_SESSION["split"]);
 
  if (!isset($_SESSION["split"]) || !$_SESSION["split"])
  {
    //знач. в values может быть несколько
  $values = array("wow", "no_wow");
  //случ.число
      $rand = mt_rand(0, count($values) - 1);
      /*записываем в сессию случ.знач.кот.выпало от 0 до 1*/
    $_SESSION["split"] = $values[$rand];
   
  }
```

Внизу:

```html
<script src="/catalog/view/javascript/wow.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var wow = new WOW();
    /*если сессия split = wow то init скрипт, если другое знач, то не init*/
    <?php if ($_SESSION["split"] == "wow") { ?>wow.init();<?php } ?>
  </script>
```

functions.js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*при сплит тестах выкл. и анализ. внизу в index.php*/
  /*var wow = new WOW();
  wow.init(); */
```

Может быть, ошибка в стилях?
Там везде в inline

```
элемент {
visibility: visible;
animation-name: flash;
```

}

а в stylesheet.css

```
.wow {
visibility: hidden; /*перечёркнуто*/
```

}

т.е. при no_wow visibility должно быть скрыто?

Скрин  [консоли браузера](https://upload.akusherstvo.ru/image1625240.jpg)

index.php [Код полностью](https://pastebin.com/Z1RgqCqe)

Answer (score 0):

В шапке убрать подключение скрипта

```js
<!--<script src="/catalog/view/javascript/wow.js"></script>-->
```

Внизу подключить

```js
<script src="/catalog/view/javascript/wow.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var wow = new WOW();
    /*если сессия split = wow то init скрипт, если другое знач, то не init*/
    <?php if ($_SESSION["split"] == "wow") { ?>wow.init();<?php } ?>
  </script>
```

В common.js убрать

```js
new WOW().init();
```